# Determining Convergence or Divergence with Alternating Series Test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have this problem:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{4}{(\ln(n))^2}$$

I have $b_n = \frac{4}{(\ln(n))^2}$ but I'm confused on how to take the limit of 
$\lim_{n\to \infty}(-1)^n\frac{4}{(\ln(n))^2}$. Would it just look something like:
$$\frac{4}{(\ln(\infty))^2} = \frac{4}{0}? = diverge?$$

Natural logs are confusing.

Comment: No, of course not: $$\log n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty\implies \frac4{\log n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\ldots$$ The squared logarithm has the very same effect.

Comment: $\ln (\infty) = 0$ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that by [alernating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)

$$\sum (-1)^n a_n$$

converges when

- $a_n \to 0$
- $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing

then note that

$$\log n \to \infty \implies \frac 4{\log n} \to 0$$